# Graphics and Animation in C#

Tags: c#, flash, animation, windows-forms-designer

I created a Game in C# (Multi-player Tanks Game) using Windows Forms Tools (Panels, shapes, buttons, etc...) but the **Animation** and **Graphics** are just so poor, so is there any Type of simple Graphics or Animation to use in C# to make this game a little better, can I use flash in C#, anything?!!!

Comment: You might also be interested in our sister site [GameDev.SE].

Answer (score 1):

XNA is great, its a completely different technology to Windows Forms as its based on DirectX.

Another idea is to check out silverlight or WPF depending on how complex your game is. For simple 2D games with not too busy screens it might be a lot easier than XNA.

I found a great example of [building a multiplayer game in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235236/Writing-a-Multplayer-Game-in-WPF).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at [Microsoft XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you want to improve the graphics of your game you're going to have to use design software or hire someone to do it for you. A simple look up on Google will direct you to model development software.

A good place to start is the microsoft XNA framework.

I also recommend using Blender: http://www.blender.org/

It's a completely free open source 3D model creation program.

Answer (score 0):

There are many librarys and ways for game development in C#.

I prefer to use [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA), which is based on DirectX and developed by Microsoft itself.

But there are also many other wrapper like OpenGL wrapper [SharpGL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3144/SharpGL-a-C-OpenGL-class-library), a custom DirectX wrapper [SlimDX](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/) or using the plain [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812).

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was looking for libraries or frameworks to improve winforms experience with nice animations. My best options were XNA or [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) (OpenGL) and [SDL.Net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cs-sdl/index.php?title=Main_Page).